# Automatically sum and minus to a new column

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets i use the following formula to get the total of column A in column C for each cell and minus if column B has a value.

- C2 =A2
- C3 =C2+A3-B3 (Click and drag)

My question is if there is a formula to make column C autocomplete if column A has a value.

```
--------------------
|  A   |  B  |  C  
--------------------
| 100  |     | 100
--------------------
| 150  |     | 250
--------------------
| 200  |     | 450
--------------------
| 250  | 80  | 620
--------------------
| 300  |     | 920 
--------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should work in cell C2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A250)+ISNUMBER(B2:B250),MMULT(TRANSPOSE(A2:A250)*(ROW(A2:A250) >=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A250))), SIGN(ROW(A2:A250)))-MMULT(TRANSPOSE(B2:B250)*(ROW(B2:B250) >=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B250))), SIGN(ROW(B2:B250))),IFERROR(1/0)))`

I've restricted this to the first 250 rows of the sheet but you can amend as necessary.  You can calculate the whole column if needed but it will take a while to output if there are a large number of rows

Comment: Thank you! Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, assuming your data starts in row 1, in C1 try this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(row(A:A)=1, A1, if(A:A,mmult(transpose(if(transpose(row(A:A))>=row(A:A),A:A+(B:B*-1), 0)),row(A:A)^0),))))
```

and see if that works ?